# I am trying to make two buttons for my main menu

Tags: python, button, pygame

I used the tutorial from Tech with Tim on how to make a button in my program. I did well with the first one and made it the "Start" button, but I need an "Quit" button too but it won't work. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I already tried everything I know. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

run = True
greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 255, 250, 100, "Start")
while run:
    redrawWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)

class button2():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

run = True
redButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 300, 250, 100, "Quit")
while run:
    redrawWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a class `button2`. The trick of classes is that they can be used for multiple instances. See [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).

Just create 2 instance of `button`:

```py
greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 190, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button((255, 0, 0), 280, 310, 250, 100, "Quit")
```

And handle the events for both buttons:

```py
while run:
    redrawWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

run = True
greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 190, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button((255, 0, 0), 280, 310, 250, 100, "Quit")
while run:
    redrawWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't always have to use a class for a button, you can also use a function.
This is what mine looked like:

```
def button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```

This is what each parameter means:

x - the x-coordinate of the button

y - the y-coordinate of the button

w - the width of thebutton

h - the height of the button

active - the picture of the button when the mouse is hovering over it

inactive - the picture of the button when it is idle

action - the function that is excecuted when the button is clicked